# Rooting android is the only way to access clipboard from background in Android 11?

Tags: android, adb

I created an android app. My app is to try to access to clipboard from service subclass (background).
when the app tries to access to the clipboard from background, the following error is diplayed.
#in the logcat:

```
ClipboardService   system_server      E  Denying clipboard access to com.android.thekeyboard, application is not in focus nor is it a system service for user 0
```

From what I've found online, it appears it requires READ_CLIPBOARD_IN_BACKGROUND. so I tried the following command but it was denied.

```
shell pm grant com.android.thekeyboard android.permission.READ_CLIPBOARD_IN_BACKGROUND 

#error
Exception occurred while executing 'grant':
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission android.permission.READ_CLIPBOARD_IN_BACKGROUND requested by com.android.thekeyboard is not a changeable perm
ission type
        at com.android.server.pm.permission.BasePermission.enforceDeclaredUsedAndRuntimeOrDevelopment(BasePermission.java:453)
        at com.android.server.pm.permission.PermissionManagerService.grantRuntimePermissionInternal(PermissionManagerService.java:1491)
        at com.android.server.pm.permission.PermissionManagerService.grantRuntimePermission(PermissionManagerService.java:1444)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runGrantRevokePermission(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:2300)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:251)
        at android.os.BasicShellCommandHandler.exec(BasicShellCommandHandler.java:98)
        at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:44)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:22246)
        at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:929)
        at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:813)
        at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:4687)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:4452)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1159)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1123)
```

also, I tried excuting the following commands. in Android 10, accessing to clipboard is prohibited to protect privacy. so I found adb commands giving permissions to let some clipboard apps work correctly in android 10. I din't check android 10 and the apps. but I did the commands in my app just in case. but it didn't work as expected.

```
adb -d shell appops set com.android.thekeyboard SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW allow 
adb -d shell pm grant com.android.thekeyboard android.permission.READ_LOGS
```

```
adb -d shell pm grant com.android.thekeyboard android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS
adb -d shell pm grant com.android.thekeyboard android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION
```

Are there any way to access to clipboard from background in android 11? I don't want do routing Android...

Comment: Could you please share the commands that stopped working between Android 10 and 11?

Comment: hi @hanlog  I was confused with my works. now I described better. please check it. thank you
Before android 9, there was clipboard access, but in 10, it is necessary to grant permissions via adb, and in 11, it seems to be even stricter!

Answer (score 0):

Denial of background clipboard access is a fundamental security and privacy requirement and it cannot be compromised using the packagemanager (which clearly explains why it disallowed it).
Seee https://b.corp.google.com/issues/318032054 for some relevant background.
Question for yourself: Why does your_app (your_service) need the clipboard (when it's in the background)?

Comment: I just want to share always clipboards between phone and pc in all time. and also I won't release the app in public. just for me.

Comment: When your app is in the foreground, you can access it. However if another app is in the foreground that wouldn't be reasonable (the same standard prevents another background process from seeing the clipboard data authored in your fg app).